# Is there a way to change the DirText font in NSIS script

Tags: nsis

In my NSIS script i want to change the text of DirText string to RED in MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY, How can i do this?

Please suggest.

PS: Using GetDlgItem i am able to modify the Text box and title bar only.

Answer (score 1):

```
!include MUI.nsh
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW OnDirPageShow
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"

Function OnDirPageShow
FindWindow $0 "#32770" "" $HWNDPARENT
GetDlgItem $1 $0 0x3EE
SetCtlColors $1 ff0055 transparent
FunctionEnd
```